# Macro to find string in table in defined paragraph

Tags: vba, datatable, ms-word, reference, numbered-list

I have MS Word document that structure is defined:

- I use 3-level numbered item Heading:

## 5 Heading1

### 5.1 Heading2

#### 5.1.1 Heading3

.
.
.

#### 5.1.7 Heading3

- in Item 5.X.7 I have table with results of my experiment
- "X" can start from 1 up to approx 20

I need to search in all items "5.X.7" for tables with results.

Any idea how to select first row, first column in first table in item "5.X.7"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new, and even though StackOverflow is not a free coding service ... try something like this to get you started.

```
Sub FindTables()
    Dim doc As Word.Document, rng As Word.Range, hRng As Word.Range
    Dim splitStr() As String, tbl As Word.Table
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set rng = doc.Content
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Format = True
        .Forward = True
        .Style = doc.Styles("Heading 3").NameLocal
        .Text = ""
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute
        Do While .found = True
            splitStr = Split(rng.ListParagraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString, ".")
            If splitStr(0) = 5 And splitStr(2) = 7 Then
                Set hRng = rng.Bookmarks("\HeadingLevel").Range
                If hRng.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                    Set tbl = hRng.Tables(1).Range
                    'do something with the table
                End If
                rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
            Else
                rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
            End If
        .Execute
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: --> thanks a lot for your reply. That's true I'm very new with VBA. I've tried to find an answer for my question on google - no results. I try to fix it by using objects Lists or Paragraphs or somehow via GetCrossReferenceItems but with no success. Then I ask question here on StackOverflow. Your approach is smart. I'he got some error about rng.Bookmarks("\HeadingLevel") [The requested member of the collection does not exist] but I think I'll fix it